# I have two GPUs, how can I just let one to do certain CUDA task?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

New to CUDA, but have some time spending on computing, and I have geforces at home and tesla (same generation) in the office.

At home I have two gpus installed in the same computer, one is GK110 (compute capability 3.5), the other is GF110 (compute capability 2.0), I perfer to use GK110 for computation task ONLY and GF110 for display UNLESS I tell it to do computation, is there a way to do this through driver setting or I still need to rewrite some of my codes?

Also, if I understand correctly, if the display port of GK110 is not being connected, then the annoying windows timeout detection will not try to reset it even if the computation time is very long?

Btw my CUDA codes are compiled with both compute_35 and compute20, so the codes can be run on both GPUs, however I plan to use features that being exclusive to GK110 so the codes in the future may not being able to run on GF110 at all, and the OS is windows 7.

Comment: are you running linux or windows?  and which GK110 device specifically?  I am assuming it is a K20c ? (although NVIDIA just announced GeForce GTX Titan, which is also GK110)

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Windows 7-64bit

Comment: You mention a display port on the GK110, do you have a GTX Titan?

Comment: By default it runs on only one gpu. Select the GK110 using `cudaSetDevice` and you are done.

Comment: @Pavan: if I plug GK110 in the secondary PCIE-16 slot, and not connect it to display, will the annoying windows time-out feature get disabled on GK110 then? or do I need other settings to ensure that?

Comment: @Robert Crovella: yes, I just bought a geforce titan recently, not a K20.

Answer (score 1):

With a GeForce GTX Titan (or any GeForce product) on Windows, I don't believe there is a way to prevent the GPU from appearing in the system in WDDM mode, which means that windows will build a display driver stack on it, even if the card has no physical display attached to it.  So you may be stuck with the windows TDR mechanism.  You could try experimenting with it to confirm that. (The windows TDR behavior can be modified via registry hacking).

Regarding steering CUDA tasks to the GTX Titan, the display driver control panel should have a selectable setting for this.  It may be in the "Manage 3D settings" area or some other area depending on which driver you have.  When you find the appropriate settings area, there will be a selection entitled something like CUDA - GPUs which will probably be set to "All".  If you change the "Global Presets" selection to "Base Profile" you should be able to change this CUDA-GPUs setting.  Clicking on it should give you a selection of "All" or a set of checkboxes for each GPU detected.  If you uncheck the GF110 device and check the GK110 device, then CUDA programs that do not select a particular GPU via cudaSetDevice() should be steered to the GK110 device based on this checkbox selection.  You may want to experiment with this as well to confirm.

Other than that, as mentioned in the comments, using a programmatic method, you can always query device properties and then select the device that reports itself as a cc3.5 device.

Comment: I remember I read soemthing from some website there that if you have two nvidia gpus installed on the same system, and only connect one to the monitor, then it is possible to do some settings to prevent windows from timing-out the other gpu, I just cannot find the article at the moment...

Comment: Windows TDR can be disabled through the registry (as mentioned above) or by installing Nsight (http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) which disables it as default and makes it adjustable from its settings.